# select distinct, explode and put the first values in a drop down

Tags: php

I have these values in a table: I want to get only the first values into a drop-down list where there will be no duplicates in terms of the first values. this code works well but shows duplicates. Any help? Thanks.
media > audio > country
media > video > country
media > video > country
media > other > gospel
apparel > female > adult
apparel > male > adult

```
$sqlbrand = "SELECT DISTINCT Product_Type FROM products ORDER BY Product_Type";



                $rsbrand = mysql_query($sqlbrand);



                while($brand = mysql_fetch_array($rsbrand))

                    {   

                        if($brand['Product_Type'] != '')

                        {                   

                        $str = $brand['Product_Type'];

                         $category = explode('>', $str);

                         $catName = $category['0'];

                            echo "<option value=\"".$catName."\">".$catName."\n  ";

                        }

                            else

                        {

                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all your results in an array then use array_unique on it, then show put the result of that in a drop down list.

It is probably also achievable by modifying the SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you order by `Product_Type`, first elems the same will be grouped one after the other,   so you only need to save the previous elem and see if it's the same that the current :

```
$savePT="";

while($brand = mysql_fetch_array($rsbrand))
{
    if($brand['Product_Type'] != '' && $brand['Product_Type']!=$savePT)
    {                   
        $category = explode('>', $brand['Product_Type']);
        $catName = $category['0'];
        echo "<option value=\"".$catName."\">".$catName."\n  ";
        $savePT= $brand['Product_Type'];
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

Like C.S. has said, you could just change the query :

```
$sqlbrand = "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Product_Type,' >',1) as ProductType FROM products ORDER BY Product_Type";
$rsbrand = mysql_query($sqlbrand);
while($brand = mysql_fetch_array($rsbrand))
{
    echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($brand['ProductType']).'">'.$brand['Product_Type'].'\n  ';
}
```

Should work.

Comment: either adding value in an array and do  `array_unique` like C.S. said, then looping the array and displaying each element still in it. either using an array and for each value, if it is in the array it's ignored, if it isn't the option is echoed and the value is added in the array

Comment: I tried it. getting \n being printed out. seems its not getting the values. could it be from the SQL query?

Comment: ah yes sorry, a function it's used so the field is not anymore named `Product_Type` and it needs an `AS VarName` ( edit : C.S.-Lecours had already done it )